# Internet Explorer ignoring my cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, http, cookies, webobjects

I am having a strange problem with Internet Explorer not accepting my cookies. This is the cookie:

```
set-cookie: USUSERNAME=LrceSVu6mUJ9Ztmvp4oKSQ%3D%3D; version="1"; expires=Mon, 15-Jun-2009 11:42:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.us.is
```

It does not get stored for the domain dev-intranet.us.is or any other us.is domain. However setting the domain of the cookie to my dev machines ip address works perfectly:

```
set-cookie: USUSERNAME=LrceSVu6mUJ9Ztmvp4oKSQ%3D%3D; version="1"; expires=Mon, 15-Jun-2009 08:41:58 GMT; path=/; domain=192.168.34.104
```

Everything works as expecten in Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome but not IE7

Any ideas whats going on here?

Btw. using WebObjects WOCookie to create the cookie.

Comment: Are you connecting to the dev server by IP address, or by host name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cookie in your example is for the "us.is" domain. **IE ignores cookies set for two-letter domains**. To be more exact, it seems to ignore cookies from domains with less than 5 characters (like yours: 2+2).

I remember this bug/feature from IE6 I believe, possibly earlier versions. Reading this, it looks like the behavior is still around in IE7.

An MSKB article suggesting an unpractical workaround can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310676.

More practical is perhaps to get a longer domain name ;-) or to make sure users are always redirected to one canonical name, i.e. "www.us.is" and plant your cookies there.

Comment: I assumed that there would be a question about IE and two-letter domains on S.O. already, but in that case I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Yes this is because of the IE bug .. very good :) And the workaround suggested by MS does not work. We solved this be setting Firefox as a default browser .. luckily our applications are for inhouse use :)

Answer (score 6):

Some additional edge cases / details (tests done in IE8 using the Per Site Privacy Actions [Internet Options > Privacy > Sites] ):

The following domains are **REJECTED**:

```
  a.a
 aa.a
  a.aa
 aa.aa
```

with the error message:

```
You have entered an invalid domain. Domains must be in the Internet zone
and must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocol. URLs beginning with xn-- must
be valid IDN names.

Examples of valid domains:

  - www.treyresearch.net
  - http://treyresearch.net
  - fineartschool.net
```

The following domains are **ACCEPTED**:

```
aaa.a
aaa.aa
  a.aaa
 aa.aaa

   a.a.a
  a.a.aa
 a.aa.aa
aa.aa.aa
```

Further, and largely unrelated, Internet Explorer appears to refuse to accept domains that contain characters not allowed in the specification for domains. If (in a development environment, presumably), you have a domain that is invalid, IE does not like it.

The following domains are **REJECTED**:

```
a_a.aa
a%a.aa
a*a.aa
a=a.aa
```

with the error message: `The site name you entered is not a valid IDN URL`.

The testing seems to be limited to character validity and not arrangment validity, because the following domains are **ACCEPTED**:

```
aa-.aa
aa.aaa.
---.aa
-.---
---.-
```

Hope this helps people looking for details for why cookies aren't being set properly in IE7 / IE8 in one environment vs. another.

Comment: Thx a lot for this answer. I had the problem for more than one week with IE9. In my case it was the underscore in my sub-sub-domain name.